# Rails/HAML: Line breaks in text mail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml, actionmailer

I'm just trying to format a haml-generated (text) mailer template, and I'm having a little difficulty getting it to read multiple line breaks. Eg: I'd have thought

```
Dear
= @user.name,

Your username is
= @user.username




Your status is
= @user.status
```

I had assumed that the multiple line breaks would be read, but the "Your status is" line comes out on the line directly beneath the username. (Yes, that many line breaks is an exaggeration of how many I want, but still)

So, the question is: Line breaks in haml text messages....erm, how?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can also use `\` or `==`:

```
Dear
= @user.name,
\
Your username is
= @user.username
\
\
\
\
Your status is
= @user.status
```

This has the added advantage of allowing you to use interpolation, whereas using the `:plain` filter won't.

Comment: You can use `#{@some_ruby}` for string interpolation when using the `:plain` filter.

Comment: From a template readability standpoint, this is the correct answer.

Answer (score 14):

I'd suggest that using haml for plain text templates doesn't add anything and in most cases makes them more complex then plain old `erb` templates. It's main purpose, after all, is making markup simple and omitting the need for closing tags - this doesn't apply to plain text.

If you're sending multi-mime emails, there's nothing preventing you from using `html.haml` for the HTML templates and `text.erb` for the plain text ones, which will preserve your multiple line breaks:

```
Dear <%= @user.name %>,

Your username is <%= @user.username %>




Your status is <%= @user.status %>
```

Comment: I think this is a very good point: HAML exists to make markup lightweight and elegant. For the cases when it doesn't, there is no need for using it.

Comment: There are some things that some people prefer about HAML that are not related to html, for example, the interpolation takes up less space, and you don't have to use ```% end```.

Comment: The question was not about the pro's and con's of using HAML. The question was about how to use HAML to achieve a certain result. This answer is off topic.

Answer (score 10):

Try haml's :plain helper.

```
Dear
= @user.name,

Your username is
= @user.username
:plain



  Your status is
  = @user.status
```

*edit - you need to indent your haml text following the :plain filter as you would normally within haml.

Comment: How does putting :plain below the two lines cause "Your username is" and @user.username to be output on the same line?

Comment: Okay, I get it now. So `:plain` can be used (in fact, *must* be used -- otherwise haml will run all your lines together and remove blank lines) to insert **line breaks** in .text.haml mailer templates.

But to address the other problem (where the `Dear` and `@user.name` are output on separate lines when you probably don't want them to), this is what works for me: use the `#{value}` style of interpolation instead of `= value`. So for the salutation line, you can write it as `Dear #{@user.name}` (all on the same line) in order to get it to show up all on the same line.

Answer (score 8):

Consider another HAML approach that is more legible.

```
Dear #{@user.name},

Your username is #{@user.username}
\
\
\
Your status is #{@user.status}
```

The filename would be something like `mailer.text.haml`

Answer (score -5):

Use `%br` tag for break line. Also you can use `%p` and `%div`  and add a bit of css :)

Comment: I believe the original question was regarding *plain-text* emails generated from a .text.haml template, so I don't think using HTML and CSS would be an appropriate solution to that particular problem -- although it would work great for .html.haml templates :)

Comment: Not relevant to the original question